# Redirecting after Closing Bootstrap Modal using React-Router

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-router

So I'm using React with Bootstrap and routing with React-Router.

I have a page with some content (at `/bookmarks/21`) and when clicking on the delete button, it will open up a modal asking to confirm whether you want to delete the page. If you click No, I have the basic `data-dismiss="modal"` which takes me back to the page without anything changing. However when you click Yes, the item is deleted on the backend and the modal closes but the page doesn't redirect to the main page (`/`) like I would like but stays on `/bookmarks/21` with no content on there since it has been deleted. I am trying to avoid using jQuery but here's my current code.

```
<Link to={'/'}>
  <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={() => this.onDelete(this.props.bookmarkId)} data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
</Link>
```

I've seen the documentation recommending

```
$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
windows.location = "your-url"; )};
```

However, is there a way to do this with the React-Router? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was from a while ago but here's what I ended up going with and what I continue to go with nowadays.

You can use the `this.props.history` object that React Router adds and push the route into the array.

For example:

```
handleClick = () => {
  this.handleDelete(bookmarkId)
  this.props.history.push('/blah')
}
```

then use the method in the button `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
this.setRedirect("/blah");
```

blah being what you have set in routes.